# Помогите составить запрос для объединения таблиц

Tags: sql, sql-server

Не могу понять как объединить Таблицы 1 и 2 таблицы чтобы получился подобный результат, как в Таблице 3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно стоит задуматься над редизайном первой таблицы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее решение.

**SQL**

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.created_at
    , t2.name, t3.name, t4.name, t5.name, t6.name, t7.name, t8.name
FROM tbl1 as t1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 as t2 ON t1.bunk1_id = t2.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 as t3 ON t1.bunk2_id = t3.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 as t4 ON t1.bunk3_id = t4.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 as t5 ON t1.bunk4_id = t5.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 as t6 ON t1.cem1_id = t6.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 as t7 ON t1.cem2_id = t7.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 as t8 ON t1.cem3_id = t8.id;
```

Comment: Супер. Спасибо, все сработало. Я стал немного умнее